# Looking for websites to brush up on algebra skills needed for calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question

I've enrolled in an 8 week online Calculus 1 class, we're currently in week 2 and while I understand the calculus concepts (average rate of change, limits) I'm having a hard time on my homework due to not having a strong background in algebra. Are there any websites that I could go check out that would help me brush up on algebra, I'm mostly struggling on factoring, simplifying, square roots, Pi)

Comment: I like to use the Schaum's Outlines series as a reference for anything I need to brush up on. They have a lot of books on Algebra all the way up to (and I believe beyond) College Algebra. Take a look and see if your library has it. Also, google things like "Algebraic manipulation exercises". There are many problem sheets such as http://www.sensiblemike.com/oldsite/exercises/Resources/04-manipulations.pdf which give a lot of exercises for practice.

Answer (score 1):

Paul's Online Math Notes may be a good place to check out. You can either look it up on google or go to it here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/
It can help out with algebra as well as calculus.

Answer (score 1):

[Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra-basics) is nicely structured and has lots of free videos and exercises. For what it's worth, I usually like Sal Kahn's take on things. He's often mindful to take a step back and think about motivation and intuition before diving into the computation. This is a good habit to have when you're learning mathematics.